# Should I remove Observers of LiveData in the fragments that reference their parent Activity ViewModel?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-lifecycle, android-viewmodel

Having multiple fragments that deal with the same data I decided to use a shared ViewModel with their parent activity.

My concern is, if I do not remove the observers in the fragments, am I creating multiple instances of the same observer?

The reason I assume this, when I switch fragments the LiveData still has observers after the fragment onDetatch is called. I tested the observers with:

```
 Log.e("$TAG $OBSERVERS", "Has Observers = ${mainViewModel.materialListString.hasObservers()}")
 Log.e("$TAG $OBSERVERS", "Has Active Observers = ${mainViewModel.materialListString.hasActiveObservers()}")
```

After testing, the LiveData did have an observer('s) and an active observer('s) after the fragment was detached. To address this, I am removing the Observer of the LiveData within onDetatch of the fragment(see below). And the observers are no longer active. Is it best practice to remove observer in onDetatch()?

MainActivity we initialize the ViewModel

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
    private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this@MainActivity).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
    }
}
```

The ViewModel with the observable data. In this case *materialListString*

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val eventListener = getEventListener()
    val materialListString = MutableLiveData<MutableList<String>>() 

    init {
        *...*.addValueEventListener(eventListener)
    }

    private fun getEventListener(): ValueEventListener {
        return object : ValueEventListener {
            *...*{
                    // Setting value of observable data
                    materialListString.value = *...*
            }
            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Fragment class where we initalize the observer of the MainActivity ViewModel LiveData

```
class MaterialsFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_materials) {

    private val mainViewModel: MainViewModel by activityViewModels()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        // Attach the observer
        mainViewModel.materialListString.observe(requireActivity(), observer)
    }
    
    // Observer
    private var observer = Observer<MutableList<String>?> {
        if (it != null) {
            *...*
        }
    }
    
    // Detatch the observer
    override fun onDetach() {
        mainViewModel.materialListString.removeObserver(observer)
        super.onDetach()
    }
}
```

Comment: `.observe(requireActivity(), ...)` - why are you using activity as constraining lifecycle when you're in fragment? If you want your observer to be tied to your fragments views you should be using `viewLifecycleOwner` in which case it'd be automatically removed when fragment gets detached.

Comment: @Pawel Just tested viewLifecycleOwner and works as intended. Thanks for the feedback. Took time off from android and assumed the viewLifecycleOwner referenced where it was initialized (the activity).